# Firefox on close the browser

Tags: javascript

I am using the below to check the browser on clicking the button it should show warning message but here it is not showing the warning message while close???

```js
function closing() {
var answer = confirm("Do you wnat to close this window ?");
    if (answer){
        netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalBrowserWrite');
        window.close();
    }
    else{
        stop;
    }
}
```

Comment: `netscape.security.PrivilegeManager` hasn't been available anymore since somewhere around 2012. Together with your previous question it seems to me you're trying to do a lot of stuff you _shouldn't do on a web page_.

Comment: how do i solve this issue??

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function()
 {
     return "Already leaving?";
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: This is working only when  user interact with the page...but on closing the browser is should show warning mesage.